# How do I create vertex attributes based on vertices' neighbors' attributes in igraph?

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

For example, how would I calculate, for each vertex, the percentage of ties directed outward toward males?

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, .3, type=c("gnp"), directed = TRUE)
V(g)$male <- rbinom(20,1,.5)
V(g)$male[10] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible (not necessary optimal) solution is as follows (this is one single line, I just break it down for sake of readability):

```
unlist(lapply(get.adjlist(g, mode="out"),
       function (neis) {
           sum(V(g)[neis]$male, na.rm=T)
       }
)) / degree(g, mode="out")
```

Now let's break it up into smaller pieces. First, we get the adjacency list of the graph using `get.adjlist(g, mode="out")`. This gives you a list of vectors, each vector containing the out-neighbors of a vertex. Then we apply a function to each vector in this list using `lapply`. The function being applied is as follows:

```
function (neis) {
    sum(V(g)[neis]$male, na.rm=T)
}
```

The function simply takes the neighbors of a node in `neis` and uses that to select a subset of vertices from the entire vertex set `V(g)`. Then the `male` attribute is retrieved for this vertex subset and the values are summed, removing `NA` values on the fly. Essentially, this function gives you the number of males in `neis`.

Now, returning to our original expression, we have applied this function to the adjacency list of the graph using `lapply`, obtaining a list of numbers, each number containing the number of male neighbors of a given vertex. We convert this list into a single R vector using `unlist` and divide it elementwise by the out-degrees of the vertices to obtain the ratios.

Comment: Thanks Tamas!  Unless I am mistaken, when the male indicator is missing, it has the same result as if male=0... adding the following bold code to function neis might do it right? { sum(V(g)[neis]$male, na.rm=T **/ sum(is.na(V(g)[neis]$male)** }

Comment: that should be: sum(!is.na(V(g)[neis]$male)

Comment: Yes, that should be OK. Watch out for divisions by zero, however; in your scenario, I think it makes sense to think of the numerator as being "strongly zero". The easiest way is probably to replace NaN values in the list with zeros afterwards.